# Prove every point in $\Bbb R$ is a cut point

Tags: general-topology

Definition of cut point: A point $x\in X$ is a **cut point** of a connected space $X$ provided that $X\setminus \{x\}$ is a disconnected subspace.

Definition of disconnected subspace: A subspace $X\setminus\{x\}$ of a space $X$ is disconnected if and only if there exist open sets $U$ and $V$ such that:

- $U\cap X\setminus\{x\}$ is non-empty
- $V\cap X\setminus\{x\}$ is non-empty
- $U\cap V\cap X\setminus\{x\}$ is empty
- $X\setminus\{x\}\subseteq (U\cup V)$

So far all I understand is that I need to prove that for all points $x \in\Bbb R$, $X\setminus\{x\}$ satisfies the above four conditions. I have no idea how to assign $U$ and $V$ from there.

Comment: Well, hopefully this should be fairly obvious. One of the definitions of Connectedness (shamelessly copied from Wikipedia) is "X is connected...[if it] cannot be divided into two disjoint nonempty open sets"

Comment: I edited your post to correct some formatting. For next time, see [this guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to correctly format math. Also, I think your third property has a typo: the intersection of all three sets should be "empty", not "non-empty".

Comment: My first guess is to set U to be x and all points less than x, and V to be all points greater than x. Is this the right direction?

Comment: @JessSavoie Have you checked whether that choice of $U$ and $V$ fulfills the four points above? What point is giving you trouble?

Comment: thats what I'm struggling with, is handling those last two requirements

Comment: Oh, I missed a small detail: Your description of $U$ and $V$ aren't open. You can't have them contain $x$.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, you are struggling with the last two properties, given that $U$ is the set of all numbers less than $x$ and $V$ is the set of all numbers greater than $x$.

Property 3 says that there is no real number that is simultaneously in $U$, in $V$, and in $X\setminus \{x\}$. If a point were simultaneously in all three sets, then specifically it's both in $U$ and in $V$ at the same time, so it's both larger than and smaller than $x$ simultaneously. How many points satisfy this? Does that mean that the set of points that satisfy this is empty?

Property 4 says that any point in $X\setminus \{x\}$ is in either $U$ or $V$ (or possibly both, although that possibility is ruled out by property 3). So, if a real number is different from $x$, must it be either greater than or less than $x$?

Answer (score 0):

If $x \in \mathbb R$ let $U=(- \infty,x)$ and $V=(x, \infty)$.

It is your turn to proof, that $U$ and $V$ have the desired properties.

Comment: If you had read the comments, you would see that the OP is already trying this, and checking that $U$ and $V$ has the desired proerties is what they're really struggling with. So this answer tells us nothing that the OP wasn't already aware of.